# How do I apply json_extract element-wise in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, select

I have a column of jsons, and I'd like to extract one particular value out of it. However, this value is located under two different keywords, either feature or features. I have something like this:

```
+-----------------------+
|  Json          id     |
+-----------------------+
| {feature: 1}   123    |
| {features: 2}  223    |
| {feature: 3}   323    |
| {features: 4}  423    |
+-----------------------+
```

and I want something like this:

```
+-----------------------+
|  features      id     |
+-----------------------+
|     1          123    |
|     2          223    |
|     3          323    |
|     4          423    |
+-----------------------+
```

How can I apply json_extract to each row to get my desired value? I've tried

```
SELECT json_extract(json, path) FROM tbl
```

but json_extract only seems to work for one defined path and doesn't seem to take in variables as path.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [13.5 Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html):

```sql
SET
  @`path` := 'feature';

SET
  @`qry` := CONCAT('
    SELECT
      JSON_EXTRACT(`json`, \'$.', @`path`, '\') ', @`path`, ',
      `id`
    FROM
      `tbl`;
  ');

PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`qry`;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a9eb5273c1c57d10b9e6e63cbc260abe).

**UPDATE**

```sql
SET
  @`path` := '\'$.feature\', \'$.features\'',
  @`alies` := 'features';

SET  @`qry` :=
  CONCAT('
    SELECT
      `der`.`', @`alies`,'` ->> \'$[0]\' `', @`alies`, '`,
      `der`.`id`
    FROM (
      SELECT
        JSON_EXTRACT(`json`, ', @`path`, ') `', @`alies`, '`,
        `id`
      FROM
        `tbl`
    ) `der`;
  ');

PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`qry`;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6eed88a6205c64d161bce6afd7fddc88).

Answer (score 0):

> this value is located under two different keywords, either `'feature'` or `'features'`.

If you have a predefined list of possible keys, you can use try them one by one and use `coalesce()` for selection:

```
select coalesce(js ->> '$.feature', js ->> '$.features') feature, id
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=27278bb1d496dbc1e59b427a363acc1e)**:

```
feature |  id
:------ | --:
1       | 123
2       | 223
3       | 323
4       | 423
```